# Application does not have permission for this action

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with my facebook web app.

I want to invite a friend to an event. My app is configured with `create_event` permissions and event is with the `can_invite_friend` flag set to `1`.
Facebook say that app doesn't have the permissions.

Can someone help me?

```
$resultinvite = $oFacebook->api("/".$eid . "/invited/" . $sspId, "POST", Array('access_token' => $oFacebook->getAccessToken()));
```

Robin

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you post the code or error message you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks 
                    $resultinvite = $oFacebook->api("/".$eid . "/invited/" . $sspId, "POST", Array('access_token' => $oFacebook->getAccessToken()));

Comment: Is the access token coming back from `$oFacebook->getAccessToken()` a user access token or app access token?

Comment: $oFacebook : 

$oFacebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => CLE_PUBLIQUE,
            'secret' => CLE_SECRETE,
            'cookie' => true,
        ));
How can i get user token with 
$aVisiteur = $oFacebook->api('/me');

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also need access to user_events